# Seminorm proof of a function

Tags: normed-spaces

I have an example in a book which is not very clear to me :

let $E$ vector space made of numerical functions (or complex) $f$ defined on a set $A$. 
$\forall a \in A, N_a : f \rightarrow |f(a)|$ is a seminorm

but the problem here is that when i'm trying to verify that $N(x)=0$ then $x=0$ it's not that clear because :

if $N_a(f)=|f(a)|=0 \iff \forall a \in A, f(a)=0 \iff f=0$ which is the definition of a norm and not a seminorm.

it seems to be obvious for the author but i'm not convinced of it yet.

thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Do you mean "$N_a(f)=0$ for all $a$ implies $f=0$"? When working with a family of seminorms (specifically $\left\{N_a:a\in A\right\}$), that's the kind of separation condition you want.

Comment: yea that's what i'd like to prove but how can I say it's a seminorm family ? is it known as a seminorm to accept ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an example will help. Let $A = \{7, 13\}$. Then $E$ is the vector space of complex-valued functions on $\{7, 13\}$. Let $a = 7$; then $N_7$ is a seminorm on $E$. Letting $a=13$, it's also true that $N_{13}$ is a seminorm on $E$.

For instance, letting $f(7) = i, f(13) = 0$, we have $N_7(f) = |f(7)| = |i| = 1$, whereas $N_{13}(f) = |f(13)| = 0$. Since $f$ is non-zero yet $N_{13}(f) = 0$, it's clear that $N_{13}$ cannot be a norm, and from the triangle inequality it's a seminorm.

Comment: oh so that's something I didn't understand yea, I didn't think that it was something that you set.

Answer (score 0):

If $V,W$ are vector spaces and $|\cdot|$ is a norm (ort seminorm) on $W$, and $T\colon V\to W$ is linear, then $v\mapsto |Tv|$ is a seminorm on $V$

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hagen ! But I don't really understand how to prove that statement at first

Comment: Just verify the defining conditions (which is straightforward)

Comment: Well here is what I tried then : if I do $N(v)=|Tv|$ and I state $|Tv|=0$ then I write that $Tv=0$ and then $T=0, \forall v'\in V$ or $v=0$

Answer (score 0):

$N_a(f)=0$ does not imply $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$. It only implies $f(a)=0$.